# Excel scatterplot with not overlapping points

Tags: excel, visualization, scatter-plot

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid data points overlapping in an Excel scatterplot. I have a range of series and values, but many of the values coincide. For example, is there a way to slightly move them?

[image]

Comment: *is there a way to slightly move them?* If you move them, you would be faking the data. A value is a value, if you change the representation, you are then changing the value. Besides, the concept of *slightly* is ambiguous. If you don't mind faking the data, change the values *slightly*

Comment: Fair point, but that also depends on how it's visualized. If 10-5 would be a quadrant instead of a point, then you could put a cluster of not overlapping 10-5 values in it.

Comment: I see your point. Not tested buy maybe something like a Heatmap could help? so is *hotter** where there are more values concentrated. But to be honest, not sure how to implement that into Excel.